# run task airflow all 1 mn

Tags: python, airflow

I have a problem.
I would like to start the code all minutes and print file in folder.
He doesn't run automatically. I don't undestand why, because i had `schedule_interval`. Can you help me ? Thank you for your help !

```
    my_dag = DAG(
    dag_id='eval_airflow',
    schedule_interval='* * * * *',
    default_args={
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': days_ago(0),
    },
    catchup=False
)

# définition de la fonction de récupération des données depuis OpenWeatherMap
def recup_data():
    filepath = '/app/raw_files'

    # création du dossier  '/app/raw_files' de destination des fichiers résultats des requêtes
    if os.path.exists(filepath) == False:
            os.makedirs(filepath, mode = 511, exist_ok= True)
    # positionnement dans le dossier '/app/raw_files'
    os.chdir(filepath)
    # création de la liste des villes pour lesquelles les données météo vont être demandées
    villes = ["paris", "london","washington"]
    
    cities = {}
    for ville in villes:
            r = requests.get(f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={ville}&appid={api}")
            cities[ville] = r.json()
# obtenir l'heure et la date actuelles
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

# créer un nom de fichier basé sur l'heure et la date
    filename = f"{now.year}-{now.month}-{now.day} {now.hour}:{now.minute}.json"

# ouvrir le fichier en mode écriture
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
#    # écrire les données au format JSON dans le fichier
            json.dump(cities, file)
            r.status_code
    return r.status_code
                
#recup_data()

task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    python_callable=recup_data,
    dag=my_dag,
    retry_delay=datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
)
```

Comment: can you check if https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627199/9560594 can solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hard code a start date. You have `start_date=days_ago(0)` you should have something like `start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)`